# windows: python os.unlink raise OSError, [Error 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unlink

run(by task scheduler using a different user account)  a python script on windows and try to delete a file by using os.unlink, but got [Error 5] Access is denied exception.

```
try:
    os.unlink(file_path)
except OSError as error:
    logger.error('failed, error: {0}'.format(error))
```

2014-09-18 03:53:44,023 - error: [Error 5] Access is denied: u'C:\path\test.tgz'

Comment: Does it work on the command line? Are you properly escaping backslashes (ur'C:\path\test.tgz', u'C:\\path\\test.tgz', u'C:/path/test.tgz' all work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is run by task scheduler. There are two options to fix this: one is granting full control of the folder to the user account so that the script will be able to delete files; the other one is to check 'Run with highest privileges' in the task scheduler.

Comment: "Highest privileges" applies to an administrator when UAC is enabled. This lets the process access the ACLs that are set for administrators. A limited user (granted `SeBatchLogonRight` for a background task) would still have to be granted delete access to the folder.

Answer (score 2):

using:

```
os.system('rmdir "%s"' % path_of_link_to_delete)
```

worked for me

Comment: on a side note, any attempt to unlink a symbolic link will fail if that link is pinned to the quick access panel on a windows explorer window and there is a windows explorer window open. Closing all windows explorer windows fixed 'access denied' error for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably arent running the script as administrator, right click on the cmd "Run As Administrator" and open the script in there

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you are calling the `link()` method correctly. First off, the link method isn't supported on Windows in Python 2.x. You can only use it in 3.2 or greater. See the following for more info:

- https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.link

If you go to that link, you will notice that you need to provide at least 2 arguments. You are only providing one.

The error message you receive sounds like a permissions issue. You may need to run your script as Administrator. Does the file exist? If not, you'll have to create it. Also note that in Windows, you have to escape the back-slashes or use Python's raw-strings (i.e. **r'C:\path\to\file')**

Comment: Hi Mike, it calls unlink of a file. It was a typo. My bad